# How to add a rectange shape to a windows form and display it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created a rectangle shape and tried to show it at my form like this

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
Public Class frmBoard

    Dim baseDice As RectangleShape

    Private Sub frmBoard_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        baseDice.CornerRadius = 5
        baseDice.Height = 50
        baseDice.Width = 50
        baseDice.BackColor = Color.Blue

        Me.components.Add(baseDice)

    End Sub
End Class
```

This didn't work. I missed something, but I dont know what...

### Updated Code, after @Jay Riggs answer

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
Public Class frmBoard

    Dim baseDice As RectangleShape
    Dim shapeContainer As ShapeContainer

    Private Sub frmBoard_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        shapeContainer.Parent = Me
        baseDice.Parent = shapeContainer
        baseDice.CornerRadius = 5
        baseDice.Height = 50
        baseDice.Width = 50
        baseDice.BackColor = Color.Blue
        baseDice.Left = 50
        baseDice.Top = 50
        'Me.components.Add(baseDice)



    End Sub
End Class
```

This also didn't work

Comment: I'm gonna take a stab at replacing the two `~.Parent = ~` lines with `Me.Controls.Add(shapeContainer)` and `shapeContainer.Controls.Add(baseDice)`

Comment: @Hand-E-Food, I tried it, while trying to add the baseDice to the shapeContainer it gives error of `Value of type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for the [RectangleShape Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.rectangleshape.aspx) demonstrates what you need to do: set the `RectangleShape`'s `Left` and `Top` properties.

```
Private Sub DrawRectangle()
    Dim canvas As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer
    Dim rect1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape
    ' Set the form as the parent of the ShapeContainer.
    canvas.Parent = Me
    ' Set the ShapeContainer as the parent of the RectangleShape.
    rect1.Parent = canvas
    ' Set the location and size of the rectangle.
    rect1.Left = 10
    rect1.Top = 10
    rect1.Width = 300
    rect1.Height = 100
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Update your code to instantiate your ShapeContainer and RectangleShape objects:

> ```
> Dim baseDice As RectangleShape = New RectangleShape
> Dim shapeContainer As ShapeContainer = New ShapeContainer
> ```

Comment: Still I can't see the rectangel in the form

Comment: @mrN I copied your code and attempted to run and found you're not instantiating youur ShapeContainer and RectangleShape objects.  I updated my answer - hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

This works

Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim C As New ShapeContainer
    Dim R As New RectangleShape
    C.Parent = Me
    R.Parent = C
    R.Name = "SHR1"
    R.Width = 100
    R.Height = 100
    R.Top = 10
    R.Left = 10
    R.FillColor = Color.Green
    R.FillStyle = FillStyle.Solid
    Me.Controls.Add(C)
End Sub
```